Read the clock and time zone differences in codeigniter
I have a link to access a page that was generated using the Laravel framework and then sent in an email. The link contains the expiry date parameter, which will later read the expiry date on a page created using codeigniter.
I have a problem reading the date and time sent in the expire date parameter.
If the link is accessed using the local time zone where I am and the current time shows the date and time at which the link expires and also uses localhost, then the page from the link cannot be opened, and likewise if I change the time and time zone on my Windows with the flow the same thing, then the page from the link cannot be opened (the flow I want when the link expires).
But when the code has gone up to the development server and the production code that I created does not block the page that the link directs to and the page can still be accessed even though the link has expired (a flow that I don't want when the link expires)
This is the code I made to block the page from the link
$cekDate = '0';
$getDate = strtotime($expiredDate[0]->expired_date);
$currentDate = strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i'));

if ($getDate !== false && $getDate <= $currentDate) {
    $cekDate = '1'; //expired
}

I assume that the data from the $currentDate variable will read the time from the device of each person who opens the link, when it is local (localhost) it is safe and works properly.
But when it went up to development and production it didn't go according to plan.
When you go to development/production, the clock, date and timezone that you read are the clock from the development/production server? or how?
My default time zone is Asia/Jakarta, both on localhost, development and production servers

strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i')) will be executed on the server and it done in UTC. You can read this in PHP manual pages for those two functions. You question is long, confusing, and lacks and actual example of the input. Time is always a bit difficult to get right, the best way to go is to do everything in UTC, and only translate to local time when you show the time to an user.

A general hint: Use time() instead of strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i')). It's much faster.
